# How to debug/ test while sending .? npm react-ga [Google Analytics]

Tags: reactjs, npm, google-analytics

I am not able to debug my app using this npm, because I need to know if the page view data is being sent to google or not.
Google analytic has delay for displaying page view so I need to be able to see in console or what ever else if this package sending data or not

Answer (score 1):

Use Analytics debugger Chrome extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna

this article should explain how to use it:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/debugging

https://www.optimizesmart.com/geek-guide-google-analytics-debugging-troubleshooting/

Comment: The GA debugger plugin doesn't show anything for me while using react-ga. Does anyone else have this issue?

Comment: Can confirm that the extension worked for my react-ga use